# How to find inactive users

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to find inactive PostgreSQL users? Does it have any activity log or something like this? My main goal is to find users that have not logged for a long time?

Answer (score 1):

There is no logging of connections enabled by default, but you can [turn it on](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-CONNECTIONS) in `postgresql.conf` using:

```
log_connections = on
```

If you also want to know how long the user was connected use:

```
log_disconnections = on
```

After changing the configuration file you need to reload it, to activate the changes:

```
select pg_reload_conf();
```